# KendoUI - LESS source files to integrate into workflow

Tags: kendo-ui, less

Project utilizes AngularJS, Bootstrap and KendoUI.  Issue is, Kendo advertises that it "integrates" with Bootstrap, when in fact it only really mimics bootstrap styles.

I've got a LESS workflow established with grunt, proper Bootstrap variable overrides and all, but I'm having the damnedest time finding source files for KendoUI.

All the documentation I've come across wants you to use some Theme Builder tool, but this isn't ideal.  When you use the themebuilder, it includes a LESS file with variables, but I can't find the source LESS files for KendoUI Pro (which I've purchased a license for, so you'd think they'd serve it up on a platter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the sorry position of having to use Kendo, you have to get the source files from the `Telerik Control Panel`.

Also, have fun tracking down the variables because their scattered across the four winds within the LESS files for both the core and theme packages.